# ES File Explorer suddenly not able to view root?

Tags: file-management, es-file-explorer

My tablet is rooted, and all the "root" features on ES File Explorer are on. It's just that for some reason, after I do a search, the root files suddenly (and mysteriously) fail to show up, and then I have to disable the "root" features on ES File Explorer and re-enable them in order to see the root files again. And then it repeats itself.

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad tablet. Has anyone else seen this happen, or know what I could do?

Comment: Is this still an open issue -- or did the latest updates of the app fix it already?

Comment: I've found GhostCommander (open source) to be just as good, and it's smaller (takes up less room on limited flash space!). You can find it on Fdroid repository.